# Change image when pressed in a Service

Tags: java, android, service

I start a `Service` and call the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and display a single image. I want to change that image when it is pressed ie. a button.

I use this to capture the action i.e. a **Listener**:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //etc..
```

and I have some standard `XML` in a `drawable` which works fine for an `Activity`, but not for a `Service`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_up" />
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
</selector>
```

How can I call the selector from a service / programatically change the image?

Comment: "I start a service and display a single image" A `Service` is an android component that has no UI

Comment: and how do you use that  "selector" xml file?

Comment: @pskink: I'm not at the moment - that's what I'm trying to find out - or alternatively just how to change the image directly in the code :)

Comment: ok and how do you "display a single image" ?

Comment: @pskink: I'm dynamically creating a relative layout using  .setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), buttonImage)); and passing it a bitmap ("buttonImage"). Essentially I'm mimicking the Facebook chat heads if that helps..

Comment: is that relative layout clickable?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm capturing all the clicking via MotionEvent and the switch code I've listed in the question

Comment: you don't need any onTouch, if you call View#setBackgroundResource(int) with your R.drawable.selector it will automagically work